# Why is this regex failing

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone tell me why this regex is failing in Node?

I've tested it on multiple RegEx testers and it also works if I use a `.tif` string.

```
  // file name = ECS_6183.tif

  const extName = path.extname(path.resolve(searchPath, file));
  return ( extName === /\.tif/gi);
```

Comment: What is failing ? Can you give a little more explanation?

Comment: `extName === /\.tif/gi` this is nonsense. You are comparing string to regexp.

Comment: Because that is now how you use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Comment: Because that's not how you check whether a regexp matches on a string. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: How about just, `return extName.toLowerCase().localeCompare('.tif');`

Comment: Thanks All, first attempt using `regex` for a bool value and didn't know it needed to be passed to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line `return ( extName === /\.tif/gi);`

Should be `return /\.tif/gi.test(extName);`

Answer (score 2):

Use `/\.tif/gi.test(extName)` to test for match. `===` is to check if objects are equal, which they're not in your case.

Answer (score 1):

this is not how you should be comparing a string to a regex. Try doing something like this:

```
const extName = path.extname(path.resolve(searchPath, file));
var reg = new RegExp(/\.tif/gi);
return reg.test(extName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `return ( /\.tif/gi.test(extName) );`

**Edit**
I am sorry. I didn't actually answer your question. The thing is that === compares if two objects are equal. In this case the regex matches the string but clearly it is not the same object as the string.